# JaperReport maven Pom.xml Not creating.jasper file

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports

I am having the issue in compiling .jrxml to .jasper through pom.xml. I am not able to generate .jasper after giving mvn clean install, mvn -e compile, mvn eclipse:eclipse. Below is my pom.xml. I am sure i am missing something but not sure what. please help..Thanks is advance :)
            
    net.sf.jasperreports
    jasperreports
    4.8.0

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!--  jrxml file  directory-->
                            <sourceDirectory>src\\main\\resources\\reports\\template</sourceDirectory>
                            <sourceFileExt>.jrxml</sourceFileExt>
                            <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJavacCompiler</compiler>
                            <!--  Destination for jasper file -->
                            <outputDirectory>src\\main\\resources\\reports\\jasper</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- These plugins are used to specify correct version for jrxml xml validation -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        <version>4.8.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                 </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

      </build>

    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Comment: have you tried `jasperreports:compile-reports` as shown in the [plugin documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jasperreports-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html)?

Comment: SEVERE: Parse Error at line 2 column 439: Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null". org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 439; , must match DOCTYPE r t "null".

Answer (score 2):

Here is the snippet works for me

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/reports</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/reports</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jasperreports</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.3</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.16</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks MrsTang and Dreamer tried both it did reach my jrxml but complains about SEVERE: Parse Error at line 2 column 439: Document root element "jasperReport", must match DOCTYPE root "null". org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 439; , must match DOCTYPE r t "null".

Comment: @user2047899 in that case it should be caused by version conflict. The version of iReport/Jasper jar lib which created your jrxml may not match the version you provide in the pom.

Comment: @user2047899 please also be alert that the jasper report dependency should be unique in your pom, which implies you might have multiple version of jasper reports dependencies in your pom, just like multiple version of jasper library in your classpath.

Comment: It is when i give jasperreports:compile-reports command it is taking jasper reports jar of 1.2.0 and i am using 4.8.0 and my jrxml is created by 4.8.0

Comment: @user2047899 Well, sounds like you have already find the version to compile the reports is not quite match the one using by iReport to generate the jrxml, then no double to that error.

Comment: Finally i was able to get the jasper, but i am not able to get the path of it.File file = new File(ReportConnection.class.getClassLoader().getResource("src/main/jasperreports/sample_Report.jasper") it keeps saying it is null.

Comment: @user2047899 How about "/src/main/jasperreports‌​/sample_Report.jasper"? hope that one slash can help a little bit :)

Comment: if i give complete path (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject("C:/eslipse/trunk/***/***/***/src/main/resources/sample.jasper"); it works but if i try to read with inputstream,getAbsolutepath , it returns null